# Mount VHD In Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, vhd, virtual-drive

How would one go about mount a VHD created a something like Disc2VHD in ubuntu , try the usual mount commands but cant seem to get it going

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently [vdfuse](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=17574) can be used to mount them.

Answer (score 0):

This answer from Apr 7 '10 at 15:25 by 
Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams might be outdated, because vdfuse has stopped, don't know.

I have found this recently. 
This article describes how to use qemu-kvm packge to mount the vhd file as a drive.

It works under Ubuntu 13.10, but I haven't checked its long term reliability.

http://bethesignal.org/blog/2011/01/05/how-to-mount-virtualbox-vdi-image/

Comment: Apparently this is not working for `.vhd` files, tested on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.